# Bluetooth LE, how LightBlue (iOS version) can list devices that cannot be found by CoreBluetooth (iOS)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

This question goes for iOS but needs a short brief. I made two different apps: one for iOS using CoreBluetooth and one made for node.js - noble (Raspbian). Both work identically: they list all available devices.

They work well, they list my computer, my TV, my neighbour's stuff.

I found a strange phenomenon. My Garmin watch cannot be listed by any of these apps. No surprise there. But somehow LiteBlue (on iOS) is able to list it, interrogate it and I could even get the notification values of my pulse.

Is there any other way to scan devices than scanForPeripherals method of CBCentralManager? Do I miss some fundamental here? I assume I should be able to list the same devices as any other BLE application in the App Store. [image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show your iOS code. It *is* surprising that your code can't see the Garmin watch. It should be a standard BLE device

Comment: I will. But in fact bluefruit (another app store app) cannot see it neither. Magic.

Comment: They are probably using `CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey` to scan for devices that are soliciting the ANCS service.

Comment: @Paulw11 That was the key element.